# How do I Cascade Deletes with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I'm trying to delete in cascade using hibernate but do not know how I can delete data with 3 tables, the first table relates to the second and the second relates to the third, but the relationship is so I have a school that has n teachers, and that teachers have n materials, any idea how can I do this?

Comment: with `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE` on the OneToMany annotation of the two associations.

Answer (score 1):

To cascade deletion in `@OnToMany` associations you can either

- use `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE` which will delete all referencing entities
- or you can add the `@OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` annotation which will add an `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause to the foreign key definition during schema creation

Maybe you want to check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435251/hibernate-does-not-add-on-delete-cascade/8435890#8435890) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426979/removing-childs-from-onetomany-association-cascadetype-all-orphanremoval-t) related question.